# Swapping vue components based on store

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, vue-router

I am trying to create a vue app which will have 4 different templates, such as template1/list, template2/list, template3/list etc. the template version will be stored with the store such as store.template: 1.

I was wondering if there was a way to swap out the vue components in app to display the correct template based on this value?

router.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import store from '../store'

Vue.use(VueRouter)

const routes = [
    {
        path: '/',
        redirect: '/cases'
    },
    {
        path: '/cases',
        name: 'cases',
        component: () => import(`../views/List${store.state.tempalte}`),
    },
];

const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  routes
})

export default router
```

store.js

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';

Vue.use(Vuex)

export default new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        template: 1,
    },
    mutations: {},
    actions: {},
    modules: {},
    getters: {}
})
```

This was one of the ways I thought it might be possible but it gives me an error `store is not defined` within this line `` component: () => import(`../views/List${store.state.template}`) ``

Comment: I bet this isnt the real case but you've misspelled `template` in the import: `store.state.tempalte`

Comment: @lucasReppeWelander, Thank you for your reply, and pointing out the mistake! I surely hope it isn't the case! But I will update the code and give it a go! Nice spot!